# Download failed. cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

I'm getting this error "

> **Download failed. cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired**

while installing the plugin on Wordpress.

I have tried many solutions where they said to create `php.ini` in the `wp-admin` directory and give an absolute path to `"cacert.pem"` I've done as many solutions suggested.

Here is the path I'm giving in php.ini `curl.cainfo=/shop/wp-admin/cacert.pem` .

Wordpress is installed in shop directory.

I'm still getting the same error. Any ideas what might be the problem? Thank you

Comment: There error seems clear: the certificate has **expired**. Certificates have an expiration date. After that date the certificate must be replaced with a new one.

Comment: The expiry date of the certificate is **08/12/2018** And they **automatically** update it when expired

Comment: So why didn't the certificate update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate is expired. This cannot be solved by updating the trust store (`cacert.pem`) but only by updating the certificate the server sends.

> The expiry date of the certificate is 08/12/2018. And they automatically update it when expired.

Given that the validation is done against the certificate send by the server within the SSL handshake and not against some locally cached copy it looks like they've failed to update the certificate, i.e. something with the automatic process went wrong. Again, this is a server side problem and there is nothing the client can do to fix it except ignoring the problem (i.e. disabling validation) - which is of course not recommended.

Comment: I just **updated** the SSL and still getting the same error

Comment: @AbdulR.: if you get still the same problem than the update was wrong or incomplete. Nothing is known about the server you've updated but typical errors are that you've tried to install the wrong certificate, installed the correct one in the wrong place or forgot to restart the server so that the new configuration takes effect. Note that you need to update of course the certificate in question - i.e. if the download of some plugin failed the certificate for the site providing the plugin must be fixed and not the certificate for your personal site.

Comment: @mysticcola: This question is more than 3 years old. At this time there wasn't the current problem with the expired LE certificate, i.e. it was still valid then.

Comment: I see. My mistake.

Answer (score -1):

if you have the plugin file upload that .zip file from the control panel.

Go to the file Structure -> wp-content->plugin-> upload the zip file-> Extract the zip file-> go to the Wordpress admin panel->Active the plugin from plugin section.